# How to fix this script? Redirect Not Working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a JavaScript code to jump to a directory by typing its name. This is how it works. If the input field is empty, the user will be redirected to the page "error.html" which contains the message "This field cannot be empty." when the directory name does not exist, the user will be redirected to the page "error2.html" which contains the message "Looks like this page doesn't exist.", but there is one problem and I don't know how to solve it. I have a directory named 333, when I enter the name of the existing directory (333), I get redirected to the page "error2.html" instead. I would appreciate it if someone could help and fix the script above for me.

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0)" name="f1" onsubmit="jump();">
    <input type="text" name="k1" value="" placeholder="Enter the name of the directory"/>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="s1" value="check">
</form>
 
<script>
    function jump() {
        var directory = document.f1.k1.value.trim();
        if (directory === "") {
            window.location.href = 'error.html';
            document.f1.k1.focus();
            return;
        }
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    window.location.href = directory;
                } else {
                    window.location.href = 'error2.html';
                }
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("HEAD", directory, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Shouldn't it be simple to check what the status field contains in this case?

Comment: Did you tryed `xhttp.open("HEAD", directory.toString(), true);`?

Comment: @NicoHaase window.location.href = directory; not working

Comment: @PipoBizelli I don't know how. I guess window.location.href = directory; not working

Comment: The problem is before the `window.location...`. The XMLHttpRequest is returning somtething diferent then status 200

Comment: @Sam try this: `xhttp.open("HEAD", directory.toString(), true);` on the bottom of your script.

Comment: @PipoBizelli I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens instead? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, why is this tagged with jQuery, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: @NicoHaase I am going to redirect to the directory (333) if it exists. This is not working even the directory exists. I get redirected to the page "error2.html" instead.

Comment: @Sam this folder `333` is on the root directory?

Comment: @PipoBizelli yes it is

Comment: Maybe if you try add a `/` before the folders name?

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Couldn't you remove the redirect temporarily to check for the cause of the redirect first?

Comment: It’s seen the problem is not the redirect, but the response of request. You have to try console the response to see what’s wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You `onsubmit="jump();"` but then you just continue to submit the form without ever waiting for the ajax response. You probably want to cancel the event.

One way is `onsubmit="jump(); return false"` but some people would rather `ev.preventDefault()` where `ev` is the event sent as argument to the listener, `jump(ev)`

Tip: use the devtools with option "Persist" turned on so you can see error messages despite reloading a new page.